# Compilers: How to define this grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I must do a grammar for some compiler that I'm creating:
Binary operators `&&` and `||` and unary operators `#` and `*` in a way that they:

I) `||` that have precedence over `&&` 
II) `&&` be associative to the left : a && b && c means ((a&&b)&&c) 
III) `||` be associative to the right 
IV) unary operators have equal precedence and more than binary operators

I was thinking something like this:

```
E -> E || T | E && T | T
T -> T # F | T * F
F -> (E) | Numbers
Numbers -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 9
```

Would it be wrong ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the grammar going to be LL? LR? Even context-free?

Comment: it's a project at college, wich I'm working with my professor, he gave this to study, I'm starting to learn about compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple expressions like these, you could always start from the least precedence.

So you want to have a bunch of `&&`ed expressions, each of which are `||`ed expressions of equally precedented unary operators.

Before writing that down, look at these two rules:

```
E -> E + T
```

and

```
E -> T + E
```

The first rule makes `+` left associative while the second one makes it right associative (think about it). So you want your `&&` to be left associative and `||` to be right associative:

```
E -> E '&&' T | T         # left associative &&
T -> F '||' T | F         # right associative ||
```

The rule for unary operators is fairly easy:

```
F -> '#' F | '*' F | N    # apply unary operators without precedence from right to left
```

Finally, the most precedent is parentheses, which is as if you had an unbreakable token. Except, inside the parentheses you can have *any* expression:

```
N -> '(' E ')' | number
```

The `number` itself can be expressed by a regular expression, such as `'[1-9][0-9]*'`

Comment: Very close, but looks ambiguous...  How does this give precedence to || over && ?

Comment: @nemo, sorry, `||` over `&&` is so strange, I wrote it the other way around! Fixed it.

Comment: No. You are adding `(` and `)` which are non existent in the original expression. What you are doing is generating the parse tree in a way you _like_, not the way it goes.

Comment: Valter, you should know that the parse tree in the end gives you _the same_ expression, not something parenthesized. It is from the _shape_ of the tree that you will understand what gets evaluated first.

Comment: @Shahbaz, I remake the second case and create another one:
http://i.imgur.com/o3Fuh.jpg

Comment: I misunderstand, I was thinking that it should match the first token with the first node of the tree, but now I get it.
In the end, the tree should represent the expression although, right ?
Thank you very much for you attention my friend.

Comment: Exactly. The tree will represent the expression as the compiler understands.

Comment: Your last example seems alright. On a related subject, are you sure you want `||` to have higher precedence than `&&`? Usually in mathematics it's the other way around.

Comment: @Shahbaz Yeah, I'm sure. I know this detail, but my professor insist in this particular case though.